# How to achieve an akka scheduler inside a loop for the timely ouput

Tags: scala, timer, akka, scheduler

I got a functionality to do something over a timer inside a loop. So I thought of using akka scheduler to achieve it.
Here is my sample code (written inside an akka actor) :

```
class TestActor extends Actor {

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case num: Int => println(num)
    case Tick => loopAndPrint
  }

  def loopAndPrint = {
    val list = List(1, 100, 5, 23)
    list.map { l =>
      context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(Duration.create(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS), self, l)
    }
  }

}
```

I was expecting that the println will be called every 30 seconds until the end of the list. But it started after 30 seconds and ended up printing all the list items at a time.

How can I achieve this to print the list items every 30 seconds after the start ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using `scheduleOnce` which means that each scheduler will run only... once.

Comment: And, just a guess, but I think what you really want is `list.foreach` to configure each scheduler.

Comment: @marcospereira ... Yes i want to schedule it once , and i want timely output, foreach cant do that

Comment: You schedule 30 times to print each element. Instead, schedule once to print all the items !

Comment: @LouisF. My intention is not to print all at a time, but to print one at each 30 seconds.

Comment: hmm interesting, so what you have to do is to print the head of the list but reschedule the tail :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you loop all the Integer value and schedule a print of each after 30 seconds at once. Try to increment the duration to 30 for each loop.

```
class TestActor extends Actor {

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case num: Int => println(num)
    case Tick => loopAndPrint
  }

  def loopAndPrint = {
    val list = List(1, 100, 5, 23)
    list.foldLeft(30)((t, l )=> {
      context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(Duration.create(t, TimeUnit.SECONDS), self, l)
      t + 30
    })
  }
```

}